# como hago que funcione esta búsqueda secuencial?

Tags: java

```
package busqueda;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Agustin
 */
public class Busqueda {

    private static String nombre;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner tx= new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int [] lista ;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de espacios en memoria");
        lista= new int[tx.nextInt()];
         
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println("Ingrese los nombres");
        
         String nombres = teclado.nextLine();
         
        }
        int a=1;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre a buscar");
        nombre = tx.nextLine();
        
          Busqueda obj=new Busqueda();      
                obj.bus(nombre);
        {

    private void bus(String nombre, int array[]) {
       
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
              
                if(array.equals(nombre)) {
              } else {System.out.println("El nombre "+ nombre + " encontrado");
              }
{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, una pregunta o respuesta que solo tiene código se considera de baja calidad, considera usar el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/455292/edit) para añadir más detalles a tu pregunta como el error en concreto y la salida esperada. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

> Lo 1ro es que estas creando una lista de valor enteros "int", deberia ser de >tipo "string".

```
public string buscar(string[] array, string nombre){
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i].equals(nombre)){
      return "nombre encontrado en posicion: " + i;
      }
   }
return "no existe";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de dato a ingresar en la lista se tiene como int.

```
  int [] lista ;
```

Más sin embargo tu lo que quieres es ingresar cadenas de texto, cambiamos el tipo de dato

```
  String [] lista ;
```

Lo que hace `nextLine()` es que mueve automáticamente el escáner hacia abajo después de devolver la línea actual.

Entonces cambiamos

```
lista[i]= teclado.nextLine();
```

Por

```
lista[i]= teclado.next();
```

En la firma del metodo bus cambiamos el parametro `int[]` por `String[]`

```
private static void bus(String nombre, String array[])
```

Por ultimo utilizaremos el foreach

```
    for(String valor : array)
```

El codigo final.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Busqueda {

    private static String nombre;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner tx= new Scanner(System.in); Esto ya no es necesario por que ya tienes declarado un objeto scanner
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] lista;

        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de espacios en memoria");
        lista = new String[teclado.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese los nombres");
            lista[i]= teclado.next();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre a buscar");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        bus(nombre, lista);
    }

    private static void bus(String nombre, String array[]) {
        
        for(String valor : array) {
            if (valor.equals(nombre)) {
                System.out.println("Se ha encontrado el nombre" + valor);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("El nombre " + nombre + " no se ha encontrado");
                break;
            }           
        }
    }

}
```